# Simple example for running Kotlin coroutines with Thread.sleep() does not work as expected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to coroutines in Kotlin and wanted to try out a simple example. But the code does not run in parallel as I would have expected. How can I transform the method `sleepTwoSec()` so that it can be called inside `launch {...}` blocks and executed in parallel? If that matters: I am not interested in any return values (fire and forget) but `launchMultipleParallelFuns()` should exit only once all `launch`ed calls are done.

The code looks like this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import kotlin.time.measureTime

fun main() {
    println("main start")
    println(measureTime { blockingFunction() })
    println("main end")
}

fun blockingFunction() = runBlocking {
    println("  start blockingFunction")
    launchMultipleParallelFuns()
    println("  end blockingFunction")
}

suspend fun launchMultipleParallelFuns() = coroutineScope {
    println("    start launchMultipleParallelFuns")
    launch { sleepTwoSec(1) }
    launch { sleepTwoSec(2) }
    launch { sleepTwoSec(3) }
    launch { sleepTwoSec(4) }
    println("    end launchMultipleParallelFuns")
}

fun sleepTwoSec(n: Int) {
    println("      start sleepTwoSec $n")
    sleep(2000)
    println("      end sleepTwoSec $n")
}
```

The actual output is:

```
main start
  start blockingFunction
    start launchMultipleParallelFuns
    end launchMultipleParallelFuns
      start sleepTwoSec 1
      end sleepTwoSec 1
      start sleepTwoSec 2
      end sleepTwoSec 2
      start sleepTwoSec 3
      end sleepTwoSec 3
      start sleepTwoSec 4
      end sleepTwoSec 4                     // from the output it's clear that the calls do not run in parallel
  end blockingFunction
8.135047100s                                // runs for 8 seconds which means no parallelism
main end
```

The expected output is:

```
main start
  start blockingFunction
    start launchMultipleParallelFuns
    end launchMultipleParallelFuns           // this is expected
      start sleepTwoSec 1                    // I expect all calls to start at once
      start sleepTwoSec 2
      start sleepTwoSec 3
      start sleepTwoSec 4
      end sleepTwoSec 1
      end sleepTwoSec 2
      end sleepTwoSec 3
      end sleepTwoSec 4
  end blockingFunction
2s                                           // not much more than 2 seconds
main end
```

I've tried to use `suspendCoroutine` to make `sleepTwoSec` suspend, but the output was the same:

```
suspend fun sleepTwoSec(n: Int) = suspendCoroutine {
    println("      start sleepTwoSec $n")
    sleep(2000)
    println("      end sleepTwoSec $n")
    it.resume(Unit)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep` in coroutines. Use `delay` instead. By sleeping the whole thread, you are blocking the dispatcher, so nothing else can run on it either.

Comment: This is exactly my problem of understanding: with `delay` it works, but how could I do this same behaviour with `Thread.sleep`?

Comment: You *cannot* get this same behaviour by using `Thread.sleep`. You could perhaps simulate it with a Dispatcher with (at least) one thread per coroutine, but that completely defeats the point of using coroutines in the first place.

Comment: @Jorn Could you please elaborate a bit on your comment? Is it because it is called on a `Thread`? Assuming I don't use `Thread.sleep` but some other function that calculates something heavy. Would that be possible instead?

Comment: Basically, yes. You can see a coroutine dispatcher sort of like a thread pool. The number of coroutines that can actually run in parallel is the number of threads in the pool. If you block one thread, nothing else can run on it. That's true whether it's a `sleep` or a heavy calculation. Coroutines are designed to be either very short lived or sleeping most of the time, so the default dispatcher can handle many without issues on a single thread.

Comment: @Jorn thanks, this explanation helps me. I thought that coroutines are made for implementing real parallelism. But now I understand this is not the primary use case. Could you maybe tell me how that could be best achieved using Kotlin? When searching for it, I always get to coroutines in the end which confuses me a bit.

Comment: You certainly *can* use coroutines for parallelism, you just need to use a Dispatcher with multiple threads.

Comment: Coroutines are useful for both concurrency and parallelism. If you change your `sleep()` calls for `delay()` calls above, you already have concurrency. If you want parallelism, you should use `withContext(someDispatcher) { }` instead of `coroutineScope { }` and specify a Dispatcher that has multiple threads.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` simply doesn't know how to work with coroutines to do the efficient thing correctly.  `delay` does.  That's the only thing you should conclude from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a coroutine, when you call blocking code, such as working with files/network or doing a time-consuming calculation, you must wrap that blocking work using a Dispatcher that can handle it. There are built-in dispatchers that can handle IO and long calculations, `Dispatchers.IO` and `Dispatchers.Default` that you can use, for example:

```
// In a coroutine or suspend function:
val result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    doALongCalculation()
}
```

You can also create your own by calling `asCoroutineDispatcher()` on an Executor or (rarely) by subclassing `CoroutineDispatcher`.

You should never use `Thread.sleep()` inside a coroutine. It blocks a thread, but it's not doing IO or a calculation, so it is useless blocking and needlessly occupies a thread. If you use it with `Dispatchers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Default`, it is hanging onto one of their finite threads for nothing. If this happens in multiple places in your app, you could lock up coroutines throughout your app by occupying all the threads of the pool.

`delay()` is the proper way to wait for an amount of time in a coroutine or suspend function. It doesn't block a thread.

Your use of `suspendCoroutine` is incorrect. You **must not** call blocking code inside the lambda without doing it on some other thread and then calling `it.resume()` from that other thread when the work is done.